# How to upload a video file directly to Cloud Storage from a Flask form without BlobStore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-storage, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask, and I have a form on my web app's index page, which requires users to upload MP4 videos. I expect my users to upload 30min long videos, so the video sizes are likely going to be in the hundreds of megabytes. The issue now is that I intend to deploy this Flask application to Google App Engine, and apparently I cannot work with any static file above 32MB. Somehow, when I try to upload any video in the deployed version that is above 32MB, I get a `Request Too Large` error.

I see that the BlobStore Python API used to be a recommended solution to work with really large files on the server in the past. But that was for Python 2.7: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/

I'm using Python 3.7, and Google now recommends that files get uploaded directly to Cloud Storage, and I am not exactly sure how to do that.

Below is a snippet showing how I'm currently storing my users' uploaded videos through the form into Cloud Storage. Unfortunately, I'm still restricted from uploading large files because I get error messages. So again, my question is: How can I make my users upload their files directly to Cloud Storage in a way that won't let the server timeout or give me a `Request Too Large` error?

```
form = SessionForm()
    blob_url = ""
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        f = form.video.data
        video_string = f.read()
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)

        try:
            # The custom function upload_session_video() uploads the file to a Cloud Storage bucket
            # It uses the Storage API's upload_from_string() method.
            blob_url = upload_session_video(video_string, filename)

        except FileNotFoundError as error:
            flash(error, 'alert')

        # Create the Cloud Storage bucket (same name as the video file)
        user_bucket = create_bucket(form.patient_name.data.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload files more than 32MB to Cloud Storage using Google App Engine due to a [request limitation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-handled#request_limits). However, you can bypass that by uploading to Cloud Storage using with resumable uploads in python case use ["google-resumable-media"](https://googleapis.github.io/google-resumable-media-python/latest/google.resumable_media.requests.html#resumable-uploads).

- the size of the resource is not known (i.e. it is generated on the
  fly)
- requests must be short-lived
- the client has request size limitations
- the resource is too large to fit into memory

example code [included here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-resumable-media-python/latest/google.resumable_media.requests.html#resumable-uploads).